# create arrray in messages file with play.api.i18n.Messages with play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to retrieve an array of strings from `Messages` file. As simply value can be declared as `key=value` pair in messages file. And can be accessed in play framework as `Messages("key")`. But I am to create an array and access that in my controller. How to do that?

Comment: I am curious, why would you need to do that? Very unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to define your own sub-encoding, for example comma separated, and then split the string returned from Messages.